# ByteBuddy how to create a class with constructor calling another constructor in the class?

Tags: byte-buddy

I am trying to dynamically create a class like this with ByteBuddy:

```
Class A{

  public A(){
    this(1); 
  }

  public A(int n){
    ...
  }
}
```

does any body know how can I do this using bytebuddy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as easy as:

```
new ByteBuddy()
  .subclass(Object.class, ConstructorStrategy.Default.NO_CONSTRUCTORS)
  .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .withParameters(int.class)
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(Object.class.getConstructor()))
  .defineConstructor(Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .intercept(MethodCall.invoke(ElementMatchers.isConstructor().and(ElementMatchers.takesArguments(int.class))).with(1))
  .make()
  .load(null)
  .getLoaded();
```

Unfortunately, there is currently a bug in Byte Buddy that prevents matching self-declared constructors using this API. This error is already fixed and will be released with Byte Buddy 1.11.1.

Comment: oh ok, thank you very much. I will update my ByteBuddy I am using after the update has been released.